# MySQL Update and Select in one statement

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am attempting to do an UPDATE and a SELECT in the same sql statement. For some reason, the below code is failing.

```
$sql = "UPDATE mytable SET last_activity=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
info1=:info1, info2=:info2 WHERE id = {$id};";

$sql .= "SELECT id, info1, info2 FROM myTable 
WHERE info1 >=:valueA AND info2>:valueB;"

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":info1", $info1);
$stmt->bindParam(":info2", $info2);

$stmt->bindParam(":valueA", $valueA);
$stmt->bindParam(":valueB", $valueB);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);
```

**QUESTION:** what might I be doing wrong? I have been spending hours on this issue knowing that it's probably a small error right under my nose.

---

**Edited:**

I obtained this error message when loading the page that contains the php code:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error' in ajaxCall.php:89 Stack trace: #0 ajaxCall.php(89):
>   PDOStatement->fetchAll(2) #1 {main} thrown in ajaxCall.php on line 89

I am using ajax to call the php page that contains the above code, and when I load the php page from the browser, I get the above error message.

Line 89 is: `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Are you getting an error? Why not bind `$id`?

Comment: @chris85 the $id is obtained from the $_SESSION, never obtained from the user. I will check for an error now. and $valueA was misspelled here, it was fine in the code

Comment: did you start the session? this in light of new code in comments. You also tagged as ajax, why? any relevance?

Comment: I found an error, editing my question with the error message now. And it's a php page being requested from an ajax call @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred-ii- updated the question with more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running two queries, you need to call [nextRowset](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) to access the results from the second one.

So, do it like this:

```
// code
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->nextRowset();
// code
```

---

When you run two or more queries, you get a *multi-rowset* result. That means that you get something like this *(representation only, **not** really this)*:

```
Array(
    [0] => rowset1,
    [1] => rowset2,
    ...
)
```

Since you want the second set -the result from the `SELECT`-, you can *consume* the first one by calling `nextRowset`. That way, you'll be able to fetch the results from the 'important' set. 
*(Even though 'consume' might not be the right word for this, it fits for understanding purposes)*

Answer (score 0):

Executing two queries with one call is only allowed when you are using `mysqlnd`. Even then, you must have `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` set to `1` when using prepared statements. You can set this using:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);
```

Alternatively, you can use `$conn->exec($sql)`, which works regardless. However, it will not allow you to bind any data to the executed SQL.

All in all, don't execute multiple queries with one call.

Comment: my current code in setAttribute is `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`, how might I include your previous info while including the previous attributes at the same time? Would this work? :`$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES);`? and the `1` I'm not sure if it would have have to be as the second parameter or?

Comment: I tried the following: `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);` with no success

Comment: and I tried `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);` Does the error message coincide with this being the problem? My updated question has the error message I am obtaining.